# Binding data to view using ngHandsontable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, handsontable

I am using ngHandonstable directive and binding data as show below in my view:

```
<div class="col-sm-9" id="plastic" ng-cloak ng-init="dataLoad()">
<hot-table settings="{colHeaders: colHeaders, contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row'], afterChange: afterChange, fillhandle : fillHandle}"
           rowheaders="true"  minsparerows="minSpareRows"    datarows="db.lens" height="300"    width="700">
    <hot-column data="code" title="'Code'" type="grayedOut" readonly></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="description" title="'Description'" width="250" type="grayedOut" readonly></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="lastCost" title="'Previous Price'" type="grayedOut" readonly width="100"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="currentCost" title="'Current Price'" type="'numeric'" width="100" format="'0,0.00 '"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="percentageChange" title="'% Increase'" type="'numeric'" width="120" format="'% 0,0.00'" fillhandle="vertical"></hot-column>
</hot-table>
```

In my controller, I have this code below:

```
 app.controller('plasticController', ['$scope', '$location',  'toaster', 'plasticService', function ($scope, $location,  toaster, plasticService) {
    $scope.minSpareRows = 0;
    $scope.colHeaders = true;
    $scope.fillHandle = true;

    $scope.db = [];
   var dataLoad2 = function() {
        plasticService.getPlastic().then(function(results) {
            $scope.db = results.data;
            $scope.totalItems = results.totalCount;
            $scope.currentPage = results.currPage;
            $scope.totalPages = results.totalPages;

        }, function(error) {
            //alert(error.data.message);
        });
    };
```

My view does not show any data from my controller. How do I push the data to the UI when the async call is complete with json data?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute datarows should be db not db.lens as you have it currently

```
datarows="db"
```

Comment: @Sithelo Ngwenya The answer looks correct to me. Please accept it if it worked for you.